# Connection problems with YQL Open Data Table for stackoverflow API

Tags: support, api

I'm trying to make a [YQL open data table](https://github.com/nathanathan/yql-tables/blob/master/stackoverflow/questions/answers/stackoverflow.questions.answers.xml) for easy access to the stack overflow API. However, I keep getting this connection failure message that seems to be the result of timing out:

```
{
     "error": "Connect Failure",
     "execution-start-time": "10",
     "execution-stop-time": "5089",
     "execution-time": "5079",
     "proxy": "DEFAULT",
     "content": "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/9200513/answers?site=stackoverflow&sort=activity&order=desc&key=UI7fqGbBXBBEJky5T%2aqltw%28%28&filter=withbody"
}
```

Could this be a problem on the SO end, or am I doing something wrong in my table definition?

Answer (score 1):

YQL has a connection timeout of 5 seconds ([source](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Connect-Failure-On-YQL-Query-/1357663765672-2a16bc2b-166c-4664-b1f5-674360889ecf/))